# Getting started with JavaCC

Tags: jar, javacc

I am new to JavaCC and cannot figure out how to get it running. I am using Mac OS X and I installed javacc-6.0.zip and unzipped it. I am unable to make the javacc script accessible from my path as on typing `javacc` on the terminal I get the following message:

```
    -bash: javacc: command not found
```

How do I make the javacc script accessible from my path?

My unzipped folder `javacc-6.0` is in the following directory: `/Users/Rishabh/Desktop/javacc`

So I do the following on the terminal:

```
    PATH=$PATH\:/Users/Rishabh/Desktop/javacc/javacc-6.0/
```

Typing `javacc` next gives me the same message.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The version of JavaCC 6.0 that I downloaded today (2013.07.22) did not have a complete bin directory. It was missing all the script files!  Hopefully this will be remedied soon.

For OS X and other unix/linux variants, the missing script file is called javacc, should be executable, and should contain the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
JAR="`dirname $0`/lib/javacc.jar"

case "`uname`" in
     CYGWIN*) JAR="`cygpath --windows -- "$JAR"`" ;;
esac

java -classpath "$JAR" javacc "$@"
```

Add the bin directory to your PATH (omitting the backslash -- as pointed out by Ahmed Masud) and all should be ticketty boo.  If your OS comes from Redmond or you want to run jjtree or jjdoc, just download javacc-5.0 and copy the script files (NOT the lib directory!!!!) from the 5.0 bin directory to the 6.0 bin directory.

---

Update (2020):  Since version 6 is now harder to find, I have put a copy at [www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC/javacc-6.1.0.zip](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC/javacc-6.1.0.zip)

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, I also had no javacc and have to use

```
java -cp bin\lib\javacc.jar javacc
```

instead. This is very frustrating because all docs propose to use `javacc`, which we miss. Yet, I see that `javacc` was defined in the old javacc 5.0. I see `javacc.bat` there

```
java -classpath "%~dp0lib\javacc.jar;%~dp0lib\javacc.jar;%~f0\..\lib\javacc.jar" javacc %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Answer (score 2):

more `javacc`:

```
#!/bin/sh JAR="`dirname $0`/lib/javacc.jar"

case "`uname`" in
     CYGWIN*) JAR="`cygpath --windows -- "$JAR"`" ;; esac

java -classpath "$JAR" javacc "$@"
```

more `jjtree`:

```
#!/bin/sh JAR="`dirname $0`/lib/javacc.jar"

case "`uname`" in
     CYGWIN*) JAR="`cygpath --windows -- "$JAR"`" ;; esac

java -classpath "$JAR" jjtree "$@"
```

Create these scripts in the `bin` folder of your `javacc-6.0/bin`.

make a chmod :

```
chmod 755 javacc
chmod 755 jjtree
```

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X & Linux I just use a single script and two symbolic links:

```
echo 'java -cp /path/to/javacc.jar $(basename $0) "$@"' > javacc
chmod 755 javacc
ln -s javacc jjtree
ln -s javacc jjdoc
```

The first two lines create the script and make it executable.
The second two lines reuse the `javacc` script for jjtree and jjdoc, since it all comes from the same JAR.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first unzip the package, and add location where your `javacc` is located in your 
`PATH` environment variable.

like:
`set path=%path%;<location_of_your_javacc>;`

Comment: @AhmedMasud when he posted the question initially he didnt specify which OS he is using, after my answer he edited the question.

Comment: -bash: javacc: command not found was in the original version though. Its not a big deal anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `javacc` and `jjtree` in the `bin/` directory of your `javacc-6.0.zip`. When you get `javacc6.0` from https://javacc.java.net/, this bin directory is empty.

`javacc` & `jjtree` are scripts.

Actually i'm using Java 5.0 and i'm modified my `.profile` file to add (I put javacc in my Applications folder):

```
export
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/javacc-5.0/bin/:$PATH
```

It's working perfectly.