# Why is JavaCC not working on my mac and how can I fix it?

Tags: java, macos, terminal, javacc

I want to test my programme, so I have downloaded JavaCC 5.0, as 6.0 has issues. I have copied `/bin` to `usr/local/bin` but now when I input `javacc MyTest.jj` into terminal I get the following error.
`Error: Could not find or load main class javacc`
I've looked around to see why this error occurs, and the only thing I have found relating to this is this question
[Could not load main class in JavaCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867328/could-not-load-main-class-in-javacc)
As I am using an older version of JavaCC, there should be no issue with the PATH.
Also, while trying to find a cause for this error, I have found that it only seems to occur if the input in terminal is `java class` so why is it happening?
What can I do to get Javacc working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file structure should look like this where `.../bin` is some directory on your unix path

```
.../bin/
         javacc
         jjrun
         jjtree
         lib/
             javacc.jar
```

Of course the three jj* files should be executable.

In a terminal enter `which javacc`. Presumably the answer will be `/usr/local/bin`. Look for a directory called `/usr/local/bin/lib`. If it's not there, create it. It should contain a file named `javacc.jar`. If not, find the `javacc.jar` file you downloaded and place it in this directory.